# Collapsible items in menu administration

Tags: 7, routes, users, forms

In sites with a lot of nested menu items on a menu (e.g the `main-menu`) administration becomes painful. Is there a module which will add expand/collapse capabilities to the `admin/structure/menu/manage` screens?

This has also been discussed in http://drupal.org/node/521546 but doesn't seem to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Big Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/bigmenu) module seems to do the job. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> An alternative to core menu management - adds scalability to the admin menu management screen, by loading subtrees via AJAX (not related to megamenu & similar display modules - this is an admin-only content management utility).
>
> When dealing with a site menu that contains thousands of links, the Drupal Menu UI admin interface becomes so unwieldy as to be impossible to use. When the drag & drop functions for tree management are running, a page can take minutes to render.
>
> This module attempts to replace the all-in-one global tree view with a similar interface, but sub-trees are "collapsed" below a certain level, and can be expanded as needed.